# Inverse of Big Op()

Tags: probability, asymptotics

In asymptotic statistics, does the equation $(Op(h))^{-1} = Op(h^{-1})$ make any sense? As I understand, the big Op is for random variables bounded in probability, and by definition the inverse of big Op should not equal to the big Op of the inverse as the equation stated.

However, I've seen proofs in papers using it, e.g. Local linear regression for functional predictor and scalar response (Baíllo, A., & Grané, A., 2009), where there was a calculation in proof: $(Op(h^2)(B-bb'))^{-1}=Op(h^{-2})(B-bb')^{-1}$ where $B$ and $b$ are matrices. So I'm wondering why this is ok? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$\{X_n;n\in \mathbb N\} = O_p(h_n) \implies \frac {X_n}{h_n}-a_n\to_p 0$$

where the $h_n,a_n$ sequences (possibly constant, especially the $a_n$ one) are non-stochastic, and $a_n$ is $O(1)$ (finite, bounded and strictly positive).

Then
$$  \frac {X_n}{h_n}\to_p a_n \implies \frac {h_n}{X_n}\to_p \frac 1a_n$$

...since $a_n$ is $O(1)$.

In the above definition, the symbol $O_p(h_n)$ was used to express a property of the $X_n$ sequence. But it is standard practice to use the notation $O_p(h_n)$ as representing the term itself that has this property. Then

$$X_n = O_p(h_n) \implies \frac 1{X_n} = [O_p(h_n)]^{-1} $$

What is the $O_p()$ order of $\frac 1{X_n}$?

We argue that it is $1/h_n = h_n^{-1}$. If we are correct, it would mean that

$$\frac {1/X_n}{1/h_n}-c_n\to_p 0 \implies \frac {h_n}{X_n}\to_p c_n$$

Set $c_n = 1/a_n$ and you're done.

So,

$$\frac 1{X_n} = O_p(h_n^{-1})$$

which leads to

$$[O_p(h_n)]^{-1} =O_p(h_n^{-1})$$